# How to remove numeric keys of array after array_map

Tags: php

I am mapping my values to an array like and the problem is that numeric keys are added. Tried to use `array_values` after that but didn't help. The inner keys (the strings) should be the keys of the array. But they are a level deeper than what I expected. Is it possible to remove the numeric ones ?

```
$field_key = 0;
        $data = array_map(function($v) use (&$field_key, $ERP_DATA) {
            $out = [
                $ERP_DATA[0][$field_key] => $v[0]
            ];
            $field_key++;
            return $out;
        }, $ERP_DATA[1]);
var_dump($data);die;


array(51) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ORDER_REF"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["DOC_REF"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["DOC_TYPE"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
    array(3) {
      ["ORDER_REF"]=>
        string(1) "3"
      ["DOC_REF"]=>
        NULL
      ["DOC_TYPE"]=>
      NULL
   }
```

P.S. The desired output was manually made by me now, so it might not be very correct as syntax :). Thank you!

**EDIT**
Example array:

```
$ERP_DATA = [
            0 => [
                'ORDER_REF',
                'DOC_REF',
                'DOC_TYPE'
            ],
            1 => [
                '3',
                NULL,
                NULL
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: Please provide your source array

Comment: Done. Little example in the end.

Comment: Basically the `ERP_DATA[0]` are the field names and `ERP_DATA[1]` are values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use buitin function [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
$ERP_DATA = [
    0 => [
        'ORDER_REF',
        'DOC_REF',
        'DOC_TYPE'
    ],
    1 => [
        '3',
        NULL,
        NULL
    ]
];

$result = array_combine($ERP_DATA[0],$ERP_DATA[1]);

var_export($result);
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0ea0ed0dd61b8e835769bfdb0fc192ce&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thank you. I really have no explanation why my brain tried to confuse me so much when that had to obviously the easy way...